# How does output has always six variables even input is 7 or more?

Tags: c

```
   int i;
   int n;
   int dizi[n];       
   printf(" N: ");
   scanf("%d",&n); // user input
     
   srand(time(0));   
      
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   //
        
        dizi[i]=rand();
        printf("\n%d",dizi[i]);
        
    }
```

I tried to make an array which is sized by user input. When I put (in loop parameters) 10 instead of n my output has always six variables.

Comment: When you create the array `int dizi[n];` what is the value of `n`?

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behavior.  The declaration `int dizi[n];` uses the *current* value of `n`, which is undefined.    It doesn't go back and adjust the size every time `n` changes.  You can fix it by moving the declaration of `dizi` down below the `scanf` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two related things in your code contribute to the odd behavior you are seeing, 1. The code creates the array `dizi[n]` before calling `scanf()`, 2. Because of *1.* `n` has not been assigned an explicit value, therefore its value remains indeterminate. The size of the array you have created is therefore also indeterminate.

Aside, if the indeterminate value happens to be positive, then the behavior of your code will at least be limited to effects of using an unknown value to size the array.  (commonly called a software bug)  If however the value happens to be negative, then [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is invoked, greatly expanding the potential behaviors your code may exhibit. None of them predictable.

See the suggestions below with comments to explain changes:

```
int main(void)
{
      //int i=0;//If you create here, initialize here. 
                //But better to create i at time
                //  it is needed i.e. in for loop
      int n=0;//initialize
            
      printf(" N: ");
      if(scanf("%d",&n) != 1) // user input
      {
          printf("scanf failed");
          return 0;
      }

      int dizi[n]; //move this declaration after value is set
      srand(time(0));
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){   //declare i at time it is needed
            dizi[i]=rand();
            printf("\n%d",dizi[i]);         
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initializing `n` is actually useful here since `scanf` may fail.

Comment: The return value of `scanf` should always be checked, and considered an error if it doesn't match the expected number of items to be assigned (1 here).

Comment: @Luatic - agreed, and to your point, return of `scanf` should also be checked before allowing code to continue.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart -agreed.  was editing that in when you commented.

Comment: I disagree with the recommendations in this answer, they are *not* best practice. In particular, don’t initialise variables with random values. Instead, declare variables only when you need them, rather than before. That way there’s rarely any need for dummy values to begin with (arguably there is for `n`, but that just trades one UB for another).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I made only three recommendations here, to initialize any variable at the time it is declared, to move the VLA declaration _after_ value for 'n' had been set and to check return of `scanf`.  In this code, `n` is created at the time it is needed, so the only variable left is `i`, which could be created at the time it is first used in the `for` statement.  I don't disagree with any of this. But `i` is the only thing I can see that would be _not best practice_.  What other recommendations do you disagree with?

Comment: @ryyker In addition to pre-declaring and initialising the variables (two separate points), the other (implicit) recommendation that I disagree with is the formatting of your entire function. I would recommend inverting the `if` statement so that it forms a guard clause which exits the function early if `scanf()` fails.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Okay.   That would be cleaner.  Edited to address your suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your compiler has no idea what the value of `n` would be in

```
int n;
int dizi[n];
```

to start a **Variable-length-array** on stack for you. This is `undefined behavior` (you call it garbage value of `n`) and it depends on which value had previously been in stack location where compiler defines `n`. In your case it has been 6, but could have been anything else.

Comment: `n` has an indeterminate value before being initialized, which is different from undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Once the uninitialized object is used, the behavior will be undefined. In first line, it is uninitialized value, and in second line to define as an array size, generates undefined behavior.

Comment: No, it does not. When program control reaches `int dizi[n];`, some value will be used for `n`, per C 2018 6.7.9 10. If that value is positive, then `dizi` will be created (memory will be reserved for it), and execution will continue normally. If it is non-positive, then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. But this is not automatic; it depends on which value is used for `n`. Understanding the differences is important for debugging, since, when a program exhibits behavior that cannot be caused merely by an indeterminate value, it must have a bug other than a missing initialization.